# How to get id from button modal to django views

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to get the id from the modals button to select the id for the context object get id. the sample script is like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary see-details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" data-id="{{data.id}}">Detail</button>
```

and I call the "data-id" from the button to javascript

```
    $(".see-details").on('click', function (){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-bodys").html(`
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <h1>{{students.name}}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    `)
})
```

I want to retrieve the id of the javascript variable to put into get id in the context in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from profil.models import students,data

def index(request):
   ID="get data-id from js"
   context = {
      'data' : data.objects.all(),
      'students' : get_object_or_404(students, id=ID)
  }
   return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

Comment: I don't understand how your view interacts with your script. Your script isn't making a request to your server, so how do you want to pass it an id? Please take a step back and explain what you're doing: what view is rendering the button in the first place? What should happen when the user clicks the button?

Comment: When button click, then run js $(".modal-bodys").html(`
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <h1>{{students.name}}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    `)   but table students must have shorting by id in views.py

Comment: Simple Question is, How to get JS Variable into django views.py

Comment: That's not an explanation of what you want. You're talking about code, I can see what your code is doing. I'm asking you what is the **behavior** you want: What are you showing on your page in the first place? What does **the user** see when he clicks on the button? There is no such thing as getting a js variable in your view because your view is a python script running on your server and javascript is running in the user's browser on the other side of the world. The only way to pass information that the user clicks to your view is by making an HTTP request to your server.

Comment: So assuming when the user clicks the button, you make a HTTP request to your `index` view (which your code currently doesn't), then you can pass the id in the URL to the request (e.g. `/index/34`) and you should change your URL pattern to catch the id (`/index/<int:id>`) so in your view, you `def index(request, id):` and there you have the `id`.

Comment: Hmmm... Oke, the only way is by "data-url={% url 'index' index.id %}" And i get the id from url. Catch that in url.py. thanks @dirkgroten. I think thats the only way to get id.